# Hyphenation of a multiple adverb-past participle phrase

Tags: adverbs, hyphenation, past-participles, compound-adjectives

I am editing a research article, and I came across a phrase that I am having some trouble hyphenating:

"the detoxification of both endogenous and exogenous derived acetaldehyde."

My thought is that it should be "endogenously and exogenously-derived acetaldehyde." Is this way correct?  In my search I saw some rules that said to omit the hyphen after adverbs that end in -ly, but it seems like it makes more sense in this phrase to include the hyphen.  My only other question is should there be a hyphen after endogenously?

Thanks!

Comment: I would write it exactly as you have.

Comment: If you add one hyphen (and here I think it's more sensible), balance it with the other. But isn't ''the detoxification/elimination of both endogenous and exogenous  acetaldehyde' adequate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be either "endogenously and exogenously derived acetaldehyde" or, less elegantly but still intelligibly, "endogenously- and exogenously-derived acetaldehyde". Without the hyphens the adverbs both unambiguously modify the (past-participial) adjective, while with only one hyphen the adverb without a hyphen is left dangling.

Answer (score 1):

One does not hyphenate *-ly* adverbs that precede adjectives.